# Circular Reference Issue in Mongoose pre-hook

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

In my MongoDB/Node backend environment I am using Mongoose `pre` and `post` hook middleware to check what's changed on the document, in order to create some system notes as a result.

One problem I'm running into is that when I try and lookup the record for the document in question I get a `"Customer.findOne()" is not a function` error. This is ONLY a problem when I'm looking up a record from the same collection from which the model just launched this `pre` and `post` hook triggers file. In other words, if my "Customer" model kicks off functions in a pre hook function in an external file, then I get an error if I then try and lookup a `Customer` with a standard `findOne()`:

My customer model looks something like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model(
  "Customer",
  mongoose
    .Schema(
      {
        __v: {
          type: Number,
          select: false
        },
        deleted: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        // Other props
        searchResults: [
          {
            matchKey: String,
            matchValue: String
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        timestamps: true
      }
    )
    .pre("save", function(next) {
      const doc = this;
      trigger.preSave(doc);
      next();
    })
    .post("save", function(doc) {
      trigger.postSave(doc);
    })
    .post("update", function(doc) {
      trigger.postSave(doc);
    })
    .post("findOneAndUpdate", function(doc) {
      trigger.postSave(doc);
    })
);
```

... the problematic `findOne()` function in the `triggers` file being called from the model looks like this:

```
const Customer = require("../../models/customer");

exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
   this.preSaveDoc = await Customer.findOne({
     _id: doc._id
   }).exec();
};
```

To clarify, this is NOT a problem if I'm using a `findOne()` to lookup a record from a different collection in this same `triggers` file. Then it works fine. See below when finding a `Contact` -- no problem here:

```
const Contact = require("../../models/contact");

exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
   this.preSaveDoc = await Contact.findOne({
     _id: doc._id
   }).exec();
};
```

The workaround I've found is to use Mongo instead of Mongoose, like so:

```
exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
  let MongoClient = await require("../../config/database")();
  let db = MongoClient.connection.db;

  db.collection("customers")
    .findOne({ _id: doc._id })
    .then(doc => {
      this.preSaveDoc = doc;
    });
}
```

... but I'd prefer to use Mongoose syntax here. How can I use a `findOne()` in a pre-hook function being called from the same model/collection as the lookup type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ran similar issue few days ago.
Effectively it is a circular dependency problem. When you call .findOne() on your customer model it doesn't exist as it is not exported yet.
You should probably try something like that :

```
const customerSchema = mongoose.Schema(...);

customerSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  const customer = await Customer.findOne({
    _id: this._id
  }).exec();
  trigger.setPreSaveDoc(customer);
  next();
})

const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema)

module.export Customer;
```

Here customer will be defined because it is not called (the pre hook) before its creation.

As an easier way (I am not sure about it) but you could try to move the Contact import in your Trigger file under the save function export. That way I think the decencies may works.

Did it helps ?

Comment: I had thought something like this was potentially at play as well. That it's called before it's created. I will give this a try, thanks.

Comment: I just saw that I had forgotten to send the customer to your trigger Object.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making an api call and saving response of those calls directly  into db then you could get mentioned issues ,you need to extract data from response and then save it .
apiCallResponse.data

Answer (score 0):

@Veldars is correct, but they are another scenario that the error can occur, which is the scenario whereby you want to do a Mongoose update Transaction and you fail to pass the condition object that mongoose has to follow to make changes to the data, with such, Mongoose will throw: `MongooseError: a circular reference in the update value, updateValue:..` error

```
For instance: 
...SchemaUser({
   fname: {
      type: String,
   },
   lname: {
     type: String,
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('SchemaUser', SchemaUser);
```

> Wrong implementation

```
SchemaUser.updateOne({fname: 'Gabriel', lname: 'Jacob'});
```

> Right implementation

```
SchemaUser.updateOne({conditionKey: conditionValue}, {fname: 'Gabriel',lname: 'Jacob'});
```

from the above Mongoose Transaction, you can see that I omitted passing a conditional statement object

> {conditionKey: conditionValue}

Which can prompt Mongoose to throw the aforementioned error too.

> Solution 1: You can try tying your Transaction statement in a `try block` to catch a callback error log to have a comprehensive view of where the error is coming from.
> Solution 2: Do a quick check on your Mongoose transaction to ensure you haven't forgot to add transaction condition object.